# Фиксированная сетка в chartist.js

Tags: javascript, диаграммы

Фиксированную сетку задаю вот так:

```js
let options = {
  width: 500,
  height: 200,
  high: 10000,
  low: 0,
  divisor: 100,
  axisX: {
    ticks: [1, 4, 8, 12, 16],
    showGrid: true,
    showLabel: true
  },
  axisY: {
    showGrid: true,
    showLabel: true,
    onlyInteger: true
  }
};
let data = {
  labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
  series: [
    [506, 43, 543, 324, 454, 56, 453, 5657, 343, 453, 434, 568, 921, 343, 553, 435]
  ]
};

new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.11.0/chartist.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.11.0/chartist.js"></script>
<div class="ct-chart"></div>
```

По вертикальной оси Y все в порядке, но когда начинает рисоваться график, то по оси X на каждую точку рисуется линия сетки вот так:

Вопрос: как сделать чтобы не на каждую точку рисовалась сетка, а например, одна вертикальная полоса сетки на каждые 4 точки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```
let options = {
  axisX: {
    labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, index) {
      return index % 4 === 0 ? value : null;
    }
  }
};
```

```js
let options = {
  width: 500,
  height: 200,
  high: 10000,
  low: 0,
  divisor: 100,
  axisX: {
    labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, index) {
      return index % 4 === 0 ? value : null;
    },
    ticks: [1, 4, 8, 12, 16],
    showGrid: true,
    showLabel: true
  },
  axisY: {
    showGrid: true,
    showLabel: true,
    onlyInteger: true
  }
};
let data = {
  labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
  series: [
    [506, 43, 543, 324, 454, 56, 453, 5657, 343, 453, 434, 568, 921, 343, 553, 435]
  ]
};

new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.11.0/chartist.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.11.0/chartist.js"></script>
<div class="ct-chart"></div>
```

найдено в [примерах](https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html)